# Definition of message field type frame_id std_msgs/Header?

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What values are possible for the message field `frame_id` in std_msgs/Header messages? From the [message type definition](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Header.html) it is not clear to me if it is allowed to be `"0"` and `"1"` or `"no frame"` and `"global frame"`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293619/definition-of-message-field-type-frame_id-std_msgs/header?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any string value is actually valid.

The comments on the field in the msg defs are wrong / confusing: I believe that `0` and `1` were valid values way-back-when, but very quickly it was realised that they actually don't make much sense (what does "the global frame" actually mean? etc).

These days valid values are strings, and those strings are supposed to be TF frame names (but that is not enforced anywhere (I'm also not sure how that would have to be done)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) on 2018-06-11**:
I think rviz maps the messages based on frame_id matching the tf frame name. This is sort of enforcement if you want to use rqt

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-11**:
That would not be just RViz, but the general purpose of the `frame_id`.

But that is at best implicit, and not enforced anywhere (ie: invalid values are not rejected, they'll just result in problems in consuming nodes).

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-06-11**:
I do not care about rviz here. The answer given is exactly what I was looking for. Thx.